# Is there any metaprogramming patterns catalog for Python?

Tags: python, design-patterns, metaprogramming, idioms

I have just read Python Cookbook. The book is amazing.

I think the best use of this book is that it provides lots of examples that show python in real problem applications. Many of the idioms include metaprogramming techniques.

I wonder if there is any catalog that summarizes metaprogramming idioms in Python?

Python Cookbook is very rich in examples and techniques. But I think there is also a need for a pattern catalog that gives specific names for each technique and that abstracts the main features of the solution technique from the concrete application area as the Design Patterns book of Gang of Four does.

Answer (score 4):

- [A Primer on Python Metaclass Programming](http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/python/2003/04/17/metaclasses.html).
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-pymeta.html